# can I install and run my androidTest.apk on android phone?

Tags: android, ui-automation, android-uiautomator, android-instrumentation

> i have implemented UIAutomator with my android app. i am able to run
> test cases using "connectedAndroidTest" in verification option in
> gradle task and find reports on path
> "app\build\reports\androidTests\connected"
>
> all are working fine, in this scenario my phone is connected to PC.
>
> My requirement is that i want to make an apk "androidTest.apk" for
> instrumentaion(UiAutomator) test and copy it to android phone and install. after
> that i can run testcase using this apk and want to find reports also.
> in this scenario phone is disconnected from PC
>
> Is it possible?. if possible then how i can achieve it or if not possible
> then reason for it.

Answer (score 1):

You need `adb` to start the Instrumentation. If you are planning to start it from an Activity it will fail.